# Выделить из ссылки часть текста

Tags: jquery, url, javascript

Приветствую.

Имеются ссылки такого вида: http://site.ru/product-category/transport/air/

Задача: вытащить в переменную текст после предпоследнего слэша, то бишь чтоб вместо:

http://site.ru/product-category/transport/air/

стало

air

То есть интересует последний фрагмент. Сколько ни ломал голову, что-то ничего не идет)
Может, у Вас есть какие-нибудь идеи? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Эээ... 
разбить строку на массив с разделителем / и взять последний элемент массива?

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = 'http://site.ru/product-category/transport/air/',
    arr = str.split('/'),
    path = arr[arr.length - 1];
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Только вот загвоздка, весь код на JQuery и почему то такой метод arr[arr.length - 1] не пашет. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: В моем случае сработало:
arr[arr.length - 2]
Большое спасибо.

Comment: Может быть, потому что в конце строки тоже есть слеш? Добавьте проверку, если пусто - брать arr[arr.length - 2], если нет - arr[arr.length - 1].